# lists in null safety issue

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

**i'm getting a null safety issue about with a list from models**

> The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is
> enabled.Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'.

**this is the code:**

```
  var productList = List<Product>().obs;
```

**modal code :**

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Product> welcomeFromJson(String str) => List<Product>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Product.fromJson(x)));

String welcomeToJson(List<Product> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Product {
    Product({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.slug,
        required this.permalink,
        required this.dateCreated,
        required this.dateCreatedGmt,
        required this.dateModified,
        required this.dateModifiedGmt,
        required this.type,
        required this.status,
        required this.featured,
        required this.catalogVisibility,
        required this.description,
        required this.shortDescription,
        required this.sku,
        required this.price,
        required this.regularPrice,
        required this.salePrice,
        this.dateOnSaleFrom,
        this.dateOnSaleFromGmt,
        this.dateOnSaleTo,
        this.dateOnSaleToGmt,
        required this.onSale,
        required this.purchasable,
        required this.totalSales,
        required this.virtual,
        required this.downloadable,
        required this.downloads,
        required this.downloadLimit,
        required this.downloadExpiry,
        required this.externalUrl,
        required this.buttonText,
        required this.taxStatus,
        required this.taxClass,
        required this.manageStock,
        required this.stockQuantity,
        required this.backorders,
        required this.backordersAllowed,
        required this.backordered,
        required this.lowStockAmount,
        required this.soldIndividually,
        required this.weight,
        required this.dimensions,
        required this.shippingRequired,
        required this.shippingTaxable,
        required this.shippingClass,
        required this.shippingClassId,
        required this.reviewsAllowed,
        required this.averageRating,
        required this.ratingCount,
        required this.upsellIds,
        required this.crossSellIds,
        required this.parentId,
        required this.purchaseNote,
        required this.categories,
        required this.tags,
        required this.images,
        required this.attributes,
        required this.defaultAttributes,
        required this.variations,
        required this.groupedProducts,
        required this.menuOrder,
        required this.priceHtml,
        required this.relatedIds,
        required this.metaData,
        required this.stockStatus,
        required this.links,
    });

    int id;
    String name;
    String slug;
    String permalink;
    DateTime dateCreated;
    DateTime dateCreatedGmt;
    DateTime dateModified;
    DateTime dateModifiedGmt;
    String type;
    String status;
    bool featured;
    String catalogVisibility;
    String description;
    String shortDescription;
    String sku;
    String price;
    String regularPrice;
    String salePrice;
    dynamic dateOnSaleFrom;
    dynamic dateOnSaleFromGmt;
    dynamic dateOnSaleTo;
    dynamic dateOnSaleToGmt;
    bool onSale;
    bool purchasable;
    int totalSales;
    bool virtual;
    bool downloadable;
    List<dynamic> downloads;
    int downloadLimit;
    int downloadExpiry;
    String externalUrl;
    String buttonText;
    String taxStatus;
    String taxClass;
    bool manageStock;
    dynamic stockQuantity;
    String backorders;
    bool backordersAllowed;
    bool backordered;
    dynamic lowStockAmount;
    bool soldIndividually;
    String weight;
    Dimensions dimensions;
    bool shippingRequired;
    bool shippingTaxable;
    String shippingClass;
    int shippingClassId;
    bool reviewsAllowed;
    String averageRating;
    int ratingCount;
    List<dynamic> upsellIds;
    List<dynamic> crossSellIds;
    int parentId;
    String purchaseNote;
    List<Category> categories;
    List<dynamic> tags;
    List<Image> images;
    List<dynamic> attributes;
    List<dynamic> defaultAttributes;
    List<dynamic> variations;
    List<dynamic> groupedProducts;
    int menuOrder;
    String priceHtml;
    List<int> relatedIds;
    List<dynamic> metaData;
    String stockStatus;
    Links links;

    factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        slug: json["slug"],
        permalink: json["permalink"],
        dateCreated: DateTime.parse(json["date_created"]),
        dateCreatedGmt: DateTime.parse(json["date_created_gmt"]),
        dateModified: DateTime.parse(json["date_modified"]),
        dateModifiedGmt: DateTime.parse(json["date_modified_gmt"]),
        type: json["type"],
        status: json["status"],
        featured: json["featured"],
        catalogVisibility: json["catalog_visibility"],
        description: json["description"],
        shortDescription: json["short_description"],
        sku: json["sku"],
        price: json["price"],
        regularPrice: json["regular_price"],
        salePrice: json["sale_price"],
        dateOnSaleFrom: json["date_on_sale_from"],
        dateOnSaleFromGmt: json["date_on_sale_from_gmt"],
        dateOnSaleTo: json["date_on_sale_to"],
        dateOnSaleToGmt: json["date_on_sale_to_gmt"],
        onSale: json["on_sale"],
        purchasable: json["purchasable"],
        totalSales: json["total_sales"],
        virtual: json["virtual"],
        downloadable: json["downloadable"],
        downloads: List<dynamic>.from(json["downloads"].map((x) => x)),
        downloadLimit: json["download_limit"],
        downloadExpiry: json["download_expiry"],
        externalUrl: json["external_url"],
        buttonText: json["button_text"],
        taxStatus: json["tax_status"],
        taxClass: json["tax_class"],
        manageStock: json["manage_stock"],
        stockQuantity: json["stock_quantity"],
        backorders: json["backorders"],
        backordersAllowed: json["backorders_allowed"],
        backordered: json["backordered"],
        lowStockAmount: json["low_stock_amount"],
        soldIndividually: json["sold_individually"],
        weight: json["weight"],
        dimensions: Dimensions.fromJson(json["dimensions"]),
        shippingRequired: json["shipping_required"],
        shippingTaxable: json["shipping_taxable"],
        shippingClass: json["shipping_class"],
        shippingClassId: json["shipping_class_id"],
        reviewsAllowed: json["reviews_allowed"],
        averageRating: json["average_rating"],
        ratingCount: json["rating_count"],
        upsellIds: List<dynamic>.from(json["upsell_ids"].map((x) => x)),
        crossSellIds: List<dynamic>.from(json["cross_sell_ids"].map((x) => x)),
        parentId: json["parent_id"],
        purchaseNote: json["purchase_note"],
        categories: List<Category>.from(json["categories"].map((x) => Category.fromJson(x))),
        tags: List<dynamic>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => x)),
        images: List<Image>.from(json["images"].map((x) => Image.fromJson(x))),
        attributes: List<dynamic>.from(json["attributes"].map((x) => x)),
        defaultAttributes: List<dynamic>.from(json["default_attributes"].map((x) => x)),
        variations: List<dynamic>.from(json["variations"].map((x) => x)),
        groupedProducts: List<dynamic>.from(json["grouped_products"].map((x) => x)),
        menuOrder: json["menu_order"],
        priceHtml: json["price_html"],
        relatedIds: List<int>.from(json["related_ids"].map((x) => x)),
        metaData: List<dynamic>.from(json["meta_data"].map((x) => x)),
        stockStatus: json["stock_status"],
        links: Links.fromJson(json["_links"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "slug": slug,
        "permalink": permalink,
        "date_created": dateCreated.toIso8601String(),
        "date_created_gmt": dateCreatedGmt.toIso8601String(),
        "date_modified": dateModified.toIso8601String(),
        "date_modified_gmt": dateModifiedGmt.toIso8601String(),
        "type": type,
        "status": status,
        "featured": featured,
        "catalog_visibility": catalogVisibility,
        "description": description,
        "short_description": shortDescription,
        "sku": sku,
        "price": price,
        "regular_price": regularPrice,
        "sale_price": salePrice,
        "date_on_sale_from": dateOnSaleFrom,
        "date_on_sale_from_gmt": dateOnSaleFromGmt,
        "date_on_sale_to": dateOnSaleTo,
        "date_on_sale_to_gmt": dateOnSaleToGmt,
        "on_sale": onSale,
        "purchasable": purchasable,
        "total_sales": totalSales,
        "virtual": virtual,
        "downloadable": downloadable,
        "downloads": List<dynamic>.from(downloads.map((x) => x)),
        "download_limit": downloadLimit,
        "download_expiry": downloadExpiry,
        "external_url": externalUrl,
        "button_text": buttonText,
        "tax_status": taxStatus,
        "tax_class": taxClass,
        "manage_stock": manageStock,
        "stock_quantity": stockQuantity,
        "backorders": backorders,
        "backorders_allowed": backordersAllowed,
        "backordered": backordered,
        "low_stock_amount": lowStockAmount,
        "sold_individually": soldIndividually,
        "weight": weight,
        "dimensions": dimensions.toJson(),
        "shipping_required": shippingRequired,
        "shipping_taxable": shippingTaxable,
        "shipping_class": shippingClass,
        "shipping_class_id": shippingClassId,
        "reviews_allowed": reviewsAllowed,
        "average_rating": averageRating,
        "rating_count": ratingCount,
        "upsell_ids": List<dynamic>.from(upsellIds.map((x) => x)),
        "cross_sell_ids": List<dynamic>.from(crossSellIds.map((x) => x)),
        "parent_id": parentId,
        "purchase_note": purchaseNote,
        "categories": List<dynamic>.from(categories.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "tags": List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => x)),
        "images": List<dynamic>.from(images.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "attributes": List<dynamic>.from(attributes.map((x) => x)),
        "default_attributes": List<dynamic>.from(defaultAttributes.map((x) => x)),
        "variations": List<dynamic>.from(variations.map((x) => x)),
        "grouped_products": List<dynamic>.from(groupedProducts.map((x) => x)),
        "menu_order": menuOrder,
        "price_html": priceHtml,
        "related_ids": List<dynamic>.from(relatedIds.map((x) => x)),
        "meta_data": List<dynamic>.from(metaData.map((x) => x)),
        "stock_status": stockStatus,
        "_links": links.toJson(),
    };
}

class Category {
    Category({
        required this.id,
        required this.name,
        required this.slug,
    });

    int id;
    String name;
    String slug;

    factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Category(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        slug: json["slug"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "slug": slug,
    };
}

class Dimensions {
    Dimensions({
        required this.length,
        required this.width,
        required this.height,
    });

    String length;
    String width;
    String height;

    factory Dimensions.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Dimensions(
        length: json["length"],
        width: json["width"],
        height: json["height"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "length": length,
        "width": width,
        "height": height,
    };
}

class Image {
    Image({
        required this.id,
        required this.dateCreated,
        required this.dateCreatedGmt,
        required this.dateModified,
        required this.dateModifiedGmt,
        required this.src,
        required this.name,
        required this.alt,
    });

    int id;
    DateTime dateCreated;
    DateTime dateCreatedGmt;
    DateTime dateModified;
    DateTime dateModifiedGmt;
    String src;
    String name;
    String alt;

    factory Image.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Image(
        id: json["id"],
        dateCreated: DateTime.parse(json["date_created"]),
        dateCreatedGmt: DateTime.parse(json["date_created_gmt"]),
        dateModified: DateTime.parse(json["date_modified"]),
        dateModifiedGmt: DateTime.parse(json["date_modified_gmt"]),
        src: json["src"],
        name: json["name"],
        alt: json["alt"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "date_created": dateCreated.toIso8601String(),
        "date_created_gmt": dateCreatedGmt.toIso8601String(),
        "date_modified": dateModified.toIso8601String(),
        "date_modified_gmt": dateModifiedGmt.toIso8601String(),
        "src": src,
        "name": name,
        "alt": alt,
    };
}

class Links {
    Links({
        required this.self,
        required this.collection,
    });

    List<Collection> self;
    List<Collection> collection;

    factory Links.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Links(
        self: List<Collection>.from(json["self"].map((x) => Collection.fromJson(x))),
        collection: List<Collection>.from(json["collection"].map((x) => Collection.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "self": List<dynamic>.from(self.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "collection": List<dynamic>.from(collection.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Collection {
    Collection({
        required this.href,
    });

    String href;

    factory Collection.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Collection(
        href: json["href"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "href": href,
    };
}
```

**and what i'm trying is to take some data from api and display it on lists, for the user can see it  .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is clear. Just use a list literal:

```dart
var productList = <Product>[].obs;
```